# Jest - writing test for events, dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write a jest test - that will check a component that makes up a row inside a table.

Something like this
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/auzpj6sh/2/

the test case is this
-- if the datepicker is changed. A call will be made to update the dropdown box.
-- if the options in the dropdown box have changed it will clear the dropdown box

```
  describe('row component module', () => {
        test('if date has changed and after the dropdown options replenished if different clear dropdown', done => {
            const DateComponent = mount(<DatePicker />),
                dateInput = DateComponent.find("input[type='text']");

           DateComponent.instance().handleChange = jest.fn();

            dateInput.simulate('change', {target: { value: "2018-01-04" }});
            done();

            expect(DateComponent.instance().handleChange.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);


            expect(wrapper.render().find('select [selected]').val()).to.equal('-');

        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you mean to address an issue?

Comment: How do you console log so you know your element exists in the wrapper? I only got pseudo case here - there are little tests in the project and nothing as complex as this before.

Comment: Given that you are using the enzyme testing utility, you should be able to call the `.debug()` method :
console.log(DateComponent.debug());
Check out the docs (https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/debug.html)